# Python Youtube API: Attempt to access Watch Later results in invalid URI

Tags: python, youtube-api

BELIEVED SOLVED: Python API only supports v1, while watch later was added in v2. [SOURCE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/EQJKi-gjxX8/discussion)
SOLUTION: Use "Experimental" API v3

---

I am attempting to use the Youtube API to access my Watch Later playlist. Below is the code I am using.

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.ssl = True
yt_service.developer_key = 'REDACTED'
yt_service.email = 'REDACTED'
yt_service.password = 'REDACTED'
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()

playlist_uri = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later?v=2'
playlist_video_feed = yt_service.GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed(uri=playlist_uri)
for playlist_video_entry in playlist_video_feed.entry:
  print playlist_video_entry.title.text
```

I am receiving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Youtube.py", line 21, in <module>
    playlist_video_feed = yt_service.GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed(uri=playlist_uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 393, in GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed
    uri, converter=gdata.youtube.YouTubePlaylistVideoFeedFromString)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1108, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 400, 'body': 'Invalid request URI', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

It would seem the URI https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later?v=2 is invalid. However this is the one stated to be used in the google documents. Am I using it wrong, or is there another issue here?

In addition if I change the URI to `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/63F0C78739B09958` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your authentication. According to [Retrieving and updating a user's 'Watch Later' playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieving_watch_later_playlist):

> Again, the link will only be present in a profile entry if either of
>   the following conditions is true:
>
> You submit an authenticated request to retrieve the logged-in user's
>   own profile.
>
> The watch_later playlist is publicly available for the user whose
>   profile you are retrieving.
>
> The API server will return a 40x HTTP response code if you try to
>   retrieve a watch_later playlist and neither of the above conditions is
>   true.

The second link would work most likely due to the second publicly available condition being met. One thing I do notice missing from your example is the client id/source:

```
# A complete client login request
yt_service.email = 'jo@gmail.com'
yt_service.password = 'mypassword'
yt_service.source = 'my-example-application'
yt_service.developer_key = 'ABC123...'
yt_service.client_id = 'my-example-application'
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
```

You should look into that and ensure that your authentication is happening properly.

Comment: I have discovered my error. Apparently the Python library only supports v1 of the API while the watch later playlist was added in v2.

I'm not sure why google has left python without any v2 support for 3 or 4 years now. But it does support v3. So I guess I'll learn the new API! My fault for trying out new languages.